# GSUtil service account failure

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I'm running debian on GCE and I've configured gsutil with `gsutil config -e`.

When I try to do `gsutil -D ls` I get the following error:

`gsutil version 4.3
checksum f6a4b1f8400e2d1d145c9ec5e9ea8d90 (OK)
boto version 2.29.1
python version 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55) 
[GCC 4.7.2]
config path: /etc/boto.cfg
gsutil path: /usr/local/share/google/gsutil/gsutil
compiled crcmod: False
installed via package manager: False
editable install: False
Command being run: /usr/local/bin/gsutil -D ls
config_file_list: ['/etc/boto.cfg', '/var/lib/postgresql/.boto']
config: [('debug', '0'), ('working_dir', '/mnt/pyami'), ('https_validate_certificates', 'True'), ('debug', '0'), ('working_dir', '/mnt/pyami'), ('default_project_id', 'e-vard'), ('default_api_version', '2'), ('content_language', 'en')]
Calling method storage.buckets.list with StorageBucketsListRequest: <StorageBucketsListRequest
 maxResults: 100
 project: 'e-vard'
 projection: ProjectionValueValuesEnum(full, 0)>
Making http GET to https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?projection=full&prettyPrint=True&fields=nextPageToken%2Citems%2Fid&maxResults=100&project=e-vard&alt=json
Headers: {'accept': 'application/json',
 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
 'content-length': '0',
 'user-agent': 'apitools gsutil/4.3 (linux2)'}
Body: (none)
Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
{'iss': '1234567890@developer.gserviceaccount.com', 'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control', 'aud': 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', 'exp': 1405436827L, 'iat': 1405433227L}
Refreshing access_token
connect: (accounts.google.com, 443)
send: 'POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: accounts.google.com\r\nContent-Length: 726\r\ncontent-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\naccept-encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nuser-agent: Python-httplib2/0.7.7 (gzip)\r\n\r\ngrant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=ASSERTIONREMOVED'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n'
header: Content-Type: application/json
header: Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
header: Pragma: no-cache
header: Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
header: Date: Tue, 15 Jul 2014 14:07:07 GMT
header: Content-Encoding: gzip
header: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
header: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
header: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
header: Server: GSE
header: Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Failed to retrieve access token: {
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
DEBUG: Exception stack trace:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/share/google/gsutil/gslib/__main__.py", line 419, in _RunNamedCommandAndHandleExceptions
        debug_level, parallel_operations)
      File "/usr/local/share/google/gsutil/gslib/command_runner.py", line 194, in RunNamedCommand
        return_code = command_inst.RunCommand()
      File "/usr/local/share/google/gsutil/gslib/commands/ls.py", line 378, in RunCommand
        bucket_fields=bucket_fields):
      File "/usr/local/share/google/gsutil/gslib/wildcard_iterator.py", line 425, in IterBuckets
        for blr in self._ExpandBucketWildcards(bucket_fields=bucket_fields):
      File "/usr/local/share/google/gsutil/gslib/wildcard_iterator.py", line 339, in _ExpandBucketWildcards
        provider=self.wildcard_url.scheme):
      File "/usr/local/share/google/gsutil/gslib/gcs_json_api.py", line 380, in ListBuckets
        global_params=global_params)
      File "/usr/local/share/google/gsutil/gslib/third_party/storage_apitools/storage_v1_client.py", line 351, in List
        config, request, global_params=global_params)
      File "/usr/local/share/google/gsutil/gslib/third_party/storage_apitools/base_api.py", line 587, in _RunMethod
        http, http_request, retries=self.__client.num_retries)
      File "/usr/local/share/google/gsutil/gslib/third_party/storage_apitools/http_wrapper.py", line 152, in MakeRequest
        redirections=redirections, connection_type=connection_type)
      File "/usr/local/share/google/gsutil/third_party/google-api-python-client/oauth2client/util.py", line 132, in positional_wrapper
        return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/share/google/gsutil/third_party/google-api-python-client/oauth2client/client.py", line 475, in new_request
        self._refresh(request_orig)
      File "/usr/local/share/google/gsutil/third_party/google-api-python-client/oauth2client/client.py", line 663, in _refresh
        self._do_refresh_request(http_request)
      File "/usr/local/share/google/gsutil/third_party/google-api-python-client/oauth2client/client.py", line 710, in _do_refresh_request
        raise AccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg)
    AccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant`

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Are you using this in conjunction with gcloud auth login?

Comment: My intention is to only use a service account. But I might have misconfigured this somehow. I will be using this from a gce instance without an external ip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because gsutil makes HTTP calls to interact with Google Cloud Storage, it can't operate on a GCE instance with no external IP.

Comment: Do you know if there are plans to make this possible in the future? It seems like a useful feature.

Comment: I can't comment on future plans, but I agree that it would be useful.

Comment: I am currently using gsutil on a GCE instance to interact with Google Cloud Storage.  See my response in this link for what I used to get it configured: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518706/gsutil-accessdeniedexception-401-login-required/36029802#36029802

Answer (score 0):

To use a service account with a GCE internal VM, you should check the Enable Compute Engine service account in the UI and give Storage a scope of your choosing.  This will expose GCE service credentials in your instance.  However, you can't run it with tools that operate over HTTP because you have no external IP to communicate from.

That means if you want to use Google Cloud Storage with a GCE VM, you need an external IP.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this Travis. I tried to remove ~/.boto and ~/.gsutil and tried again. Then I get [this](http://paste2.org/wZFUEXsb).

Comment: You also need to enable the Compute Engine service account on your GCE VM.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I have lead you in the wrong direction.  I posted another answer - there is just no way for this to work right now.  You need an external IP for your VM.